# Android list load more can't update data

Tags: android, android-listview

I have implemented a `listview` `onScrollListener`. I have 20 data that will show in a `listview` but I just want to show 10 data first. so, if I scroll the list, it will show next 10 data. I have no error in my code but the data can't be updated when I scrolled. please correct my code and need your helps immediately. thanks.

```
    public class ResultRestoActivity extends ListActivity {

    Context ctx;

    List<Map<String,String>> listData =  new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    List <Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    ListAdapter adap;
    ListView lv;

    Button btnLoadMore;

    String bank,group,city,merchant,address,telpon,handphone,bb;

    TextView tv_GName,tv_city,tv_merchant,tv_address,tv_telpon,tv_handphone,tv_bb;

    ImageButton tabs_nearby, tabs_all;

    int bil_awal = 10;
    int awal;

    int itemsPerPage = 10;
    boolean loadingMore = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        group = getIntent().getStringExtra("GROUP");
        bank = getIntent().getStringExtra("BANK");
        city = getIntent().getStringExtra("CITY");
        merchant = getIntent().getStringExtra("MERCHANT");
        address = getIntent().getStringExtra("ADDRESS");
        telpon = getIntent().getStringExtra("TELPON");
        handphone = getIntent().getStringExtra("HANDPHONE");
        bb = getIntent().getStringExtra("BB");

        ctx = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restoresult);

        tv_GName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRestoResult);
        tv_GName.setText(""+group+"");

        list = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");        

        awal = list.size()-bil_awal;
        for(int i=0;i<awal; i++){
            final Map<String, String> map = list.get(i);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
//              String key = entry.getKey();
                final String value = entry.getValue();
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(bank)){
                    listData.add(list.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        adap = new ListAdapter(listData);

        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.addFooterView(footerView);
        lv.setAdapter(adap);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                merchant = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_merchantname)).getText()
                            .toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(ResultRestoActivity.this, DetailRestoActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("GROUP", group);
                    i.putExtra("CITY", city);
                    i.putExtra("MERCHANT", merchant);
                    i.putExtra("ADDRESS", address);
                    i.putExtra("TELPON", telpon);
                    i.putExtra("HANDPHONE", handphone);
                    i.putExtra("BB", bb);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){                 
                    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
        thread.start();
    }

    private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadingMore = true;

            list = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");
            listData = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

            try { Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                final Map<String, String> map = list.get(i);
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
//                  String key = entry.getKey();
                    final String value = entry.getValue();
                    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(bank)){
                        listData.add(list.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            runOnUiThread(returnRes);
        }
    };

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adap = new ListAdapter(listData);
            lv.setAdapter(adap);
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();

            loadingMore = false;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: dont new listData again,and dont setAdapter again. just add new data to the listData and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: can you explain by writing its code? :-)

Comment: after notify set adapter adap.notifyDataSetChanged();      lv.setAdapter(adap);

Comment: Yeah don't set the adapter again. In fact try not to switch adapters in any list control... If this doesn't work, you may have to post your code for the adapter too.

Comment: i try to delete the adapter but i got an error :-(

Answer (score 0):

you can use pulltorefresh and here is the open source project of it https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh